# Getting error 401 - unauthorized with google API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, https, google-api

I'm trying to access google subscriptions api and I've been struggling with the error for a couple of days now. According to documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest I have to create a JWT token and then exchange it for access_token, which I successfully do. But when I try to use this token on subscriptions API I get response with 401. I'm working in Node.js environment:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const keyData = require('./key.json');         // Path to your JSON key file
const axios = require('axios');


function getAccessToken(keyData) {
  // Create a JSON Web Token for the Service Account linked to Play Store
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher' },
    keyData.private_key,
    {
      algorithm: 'RS256',
      expiresIn: '1h',
      issuer: keyData.client_email,
      subject: keyData.client_email,
      audience: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
    }
  );

  // Make a request to Google APIs OAuth backend to exchange it for an access token
  // Returns a promise
  config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    data: {
      grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      assertion: token
    }
  };

  return axios(config);
}

function makeApiRequest(url, accessToken) {
  config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: url,
    auth: {
      bearer: accessToken
    }
  };

  return axios(config);
}

console.log("start");
purchaseToken = "token";
requestUrl = "https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{package}/purchases/subscriptions/{id}/tokens/" + purchaseToken;

getAccessToken(keyData)
  .then(response => {
    console.log("access_token: " + response.data.access_token);
    return makeApiRequest(requestUrl, response.data.access_token);
  })
  .then(response => {
    // TODO: process the response, e.g. validate the purchase, set access claims to the user etc.
    response.send(response);
    return;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

The error:

```
{
  code: 401,
  message: 'Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.',
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Login Required.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'required',
      location: 'Authorization',
      locationType: 'header'
    }
  ],
  status: 'UNAUTHENTICATED'
}
```

Maybe I'm sending the token the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. For other people who have troubles calling Play Developer API - you just need to replace makeApiRequest function with this:

```
function makeApiRequest(url, accessToken) {
  config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: url + `?access_token=${accessToken}`
  };

  return axios(config);
}
```

Just pass the access_token as parameter, I still don't know why it didn't work with auth attribute though.